# Java - How to get http header in interface implementation?

Tags: java, rest, header, postman

I'm trying to get the x-forwarded-for header from an http request using postman with an interface method. I want to get the IP address in the implementation method, but it either comes in null or blank.

When I test using Postman, if I use @Headerparam it returns null and if I use @RequestHeader it returns blank.

DataService interface class:

```
@POST
@Path(PATH)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@WebMethod(operationName="submit")
@ExecutableBy(anonymous = true)
public Response submit(Data data, @RequestHeader(value = "x-forwarded-for") String ipAddr);
```

DataService implementation:

```
@Override
public Response submit(Data data, String ipAddr) {
  LOG.debug("ip addr from header " + ipAddr);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that "x-forwarded-for" header is there?
@HeaderParam("x-forwarded-for") works for me.

Comment: I added it to my headers in postman, key "x-forwarded-for" with some test value and when I log it in the function, it prints null. Unless for some reason postman isn't sending it over, I think it's something with my code. But I've been searching for days and mostly everyone has done it with the @HeaderParam/@RequestHeader with no issues, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: --update-- I looked at the request and you're right! Postman isn't sending it over for some reason..